# Determinant of High Dimensional Correlation Matrix

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance, determinant

According to [[1]](http://www2.tulane.edu/%7EPsycStat/dunlap/Psyc613/RI2.html) :

> The determinant of the correlation matrix will equal 1.0 only if all correlations equal 0, otherwise the determinant will be less than 1 [...] When the measures are uncorrelated, this space is a sphere with a volume of 1. When the measures are correlated, the space occupied becomes an ellipsoid whose volume is less than 1.

I tried this out with a 2D and a 3D correlation matrix (2 or 3 random variables), and its seems true. However in $\Re^n$ $(n > 3)$, this rule seems to fall apart.

Here is the experiment I did. Am I misunderstanding the theorem, or does it not apply in all cases ?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# 2 Random Normal variables (Mean 0, Var=1), 500 samples
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(2,500))
correlation = tfp.stats.correlation(x, sample_axis=-1, event_axis =0 , keepdims=False, name=None )
tf.linalg.det(corr)    # det = 0.99493116 (As expected)

# 3 Random Normal variables (Mean 0, Var=1), 500 samples
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(3,500))
correlation = tfp.stats.correlation(x, sample_axis=-1, event_axis =0 , keepdims=False, name=None )
tf.linalg.det(corr)    # det = 0.99627995  (As expected)

# 20 Random Normal variables (Mean 0, Var=1), 500 samples
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(20,500))
correlation = tfp.stats.correlation(x, sample_axis=-1, event_axis =0 , keepdims=False, name=None )
tf.linalg.det(corr)    # det = 0.72647274

# 1000 Random Normal variables (Mean 0, Var=1), 500 samples
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(1000,500))
correlation = tfp.stats.correlation(x, sample_axis=-1, event_axis =0 , keepdims=False, name=None )
tf.linalg.det(corr)    # det = 0.0   (Should be 1.)
```

It's strange, because the values of the correlation matrix are still relatively low.
When I increase the sample size, I get closer to the expected results. But still, the pair-wise correlations are pretty low, so how can I express this for the entire matrix ?

Here is part of the correlation matrix for 1000 Random Variables:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 1.0000004 ,  0.03611619,  0.00189149, ..., -0.02675138,
        -0.02670577, -0.05336628],
       [ 0.03611619,  1.0000001 , -0.05123399, ...,  0.01167946,
         0.06262611, -0.05430067],
       [ 0.00189149, -0.05123399,  0.99999964, ..., -0.06628544,
        -0.02272393,  0.03844167],
       ...,
       [-0.02675138,  0.01167946, -0.06628544, ...,  1.0000002 ,
        -0.01871989, -0.05321919],
       [-0.02670577,  0.06262611, -0.02272393, ..., -0.01871989,
         1.0000001 , -0.00384682],
       [-0.05336628, -0.05430067,  0.03844167, ..., -0.05321919,
        -0.00384682,  1.0000001 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Is there some other way to calculate the *ellipsoid-ness* (overall correlation) of a high dimensional random vector ?

Comment: How exactly does it not follow what the text says? You are also sampling way too few samples: the resulting correlation matrix will be rank deficient, always leading to the zero determinant.

Comment: The text also probably does not pertain to sample correlation matrices, where sampling requires special consideration

Comment: @Firebug, Fair point, but with my current sampling, the *inter-correlations* are still nearly zero. Is there another metric (other than the determinant) that can summarize this in a single value (maybe like an average) ?

Comment: You can trivially verify that the theory holds by checking the determinants of arbitrary identity matrices, the issue you're seeing is that *very* *slightly* *nonzero* elements make the determinant drop rapidly as the dimensions increase (e.g. $\hat\rho=0.01$ for dimensions 3, 30, 300 will give determinants of 0.999, 0.964, 0.198). There is some competition ongoing between the sampling distribution for no correlation tightening around zero and the fact that you're simply observing many more of them, though I'm not sure how you would turn this into a 'dimension-corrected' measure.

Comment: See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/192525) for the sampling distribution of $\rho$ (couldn't squeeze this into my previous comment).